# Quando eu uso um "finish()" para encerrar a activity o Android usa alguma animação de fim de activity por default?

Tags: android

Porque eu gostaria de colocar uma animação diferente, e seu eu colocar uma animação antes de colocar o `finish()` executa a animação e depois o finish com a animação dele.

Answer (score 2):

Caso você simplesmente queira fechar uma activity, sem abrir outra, você pode fazer o seguinte:

```
overridePendingTransition(0, android.R.anim.slide_out_right);
```

Os parâmetros que esse método recebe são: `(int enterAnim, int exitAnim)`.
Que são, respectivamente, a animação de entrada da activity que está sendo aberta e a animação de saída da activity atual.

Então, caso você quisesse animar a entrada da segunda activity, e também a saída da sua, faça o seguinte:

```
overridePendingTransition(android.R.anim.slide_in_left, android.R.anim.slide_out_right);
```

Você deve chamar esse método logo após a chamada do método `finish();`, assim:

```
finish();
overridePendingTransition(0, android.R.anim.slide_out_right);
```